# Resource intensive mathematical calculation method in .NET

Tags: c#, math

I have a numerical computation method in my .NET code that will be called more than 1000 times.

```
private double CalculatePressureLossThroughPipe(double length, double flow, double diameter)
{
    double costA = 0, costB = 0;
    double frictionFactor = 0;
    double pressure = 0;
    double velocity = flow / CalculatePipeArea(diameter);
    // calculate Reynods No
    double reNo = ((this.mDensity * velocity * diameter) / this.mViscosity);
    // calculate frictionFactor
    costA = Math.Pow((2.457 * Math.Log(1 / (Math.Pow((7 / reynoldsNo), 0.9) + (0.27 * 0.000015) / diameter))), 16);
    costB = Math.Pow((37530 / reNo), 16);
    frictionFactor = (2 * Math.Pow(((Math.Pow((8 / reNo), 12)) + (1 / Math.Pow((costA + costB), 1.5))), 0.083333));
    // Calulate Pressure
    pressure = (DesignConstants.PRESSSURE_CONSTANT * 2 * frictionFactor * length * Math.Pow(velocity, 2) * this.mDensity / diameter);

    return pressure;               
}
```

This function will be called in a loop, with different set of input parameters. The loop itself is quite intensive which calls the above mentioned function (with unique parameters) every time.The function although looks small is quite resource intensive.Is there an alternate way to process the method calls without using the standard members from System.Math ?

Comment: No, not really.  Using "1000" is rather arbitrary and you give no hint why that number is relevant.  Use less, linear interpolation is going to be quicker.

Comment: In a quick test, I can run this method 1 million times in ~half a second. Are you *sure* you need to optimize this method?

Comment: @HansPassant: The number 1000 is used for benchmarking my snippet. The loop roughly takes couple of minutes !! for this numerical calculation which I think is quite absurd.

Comment: It certainly is, long distance.  It isn't like anybody could tell you why that might be, you posted code that nobody else can run.  Very little point to that.  Uninstall Avast.

Comment: You have reNo and reynoldsNo.  The second one seems wrong to me.  Anyone who uses Math.pow to square a number is making a mistake.  Each one of these simple hydraulic calculations are independent; they can easily be parallelized.  This calculation looks trivial to me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the expression `(Math.Pow((7/reynoldsNo), 0.9) + (0.27*0.000015)`can be precalculated since it's not dependent on any of your inputs. In any case when you say this method 'is quite resource intensive' presumably you mean it takes a long time -  have you benchmarked it ? What would an acceptable time be ? These are the things you need to find out before trying to optimise anything.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. The variable reyNoldsNo itself depends on the input parameter. So I cannot just move it out of the method. For the time being for 1000 iterations the method takes roughly 2 minutes.!! I want to reduce it by a minute at the very least

Comment: I'm amazed it takes 2 minutes - is this with using threads / tpl / parallel for ? If so, how long does it take with just a normal for loop ? What CPU do you have ?

Comment: @auburg There is no way that 1000 iterations should take 2 minutes. There's something else wrong here. Post a compilable example in your OP

Comment: @this-me I've tested your code above (replacing various variables with constants) and not knowing the implementation for CalculatePipeArea have created a method that just returns a nominal value. I ran it 1000 times and in total it took 2 ms. A million times took 2 seconds. So if there's a bottleneck here it must be in CalculatePipeArea .

Comment: @this-Me Please post a compilable reproduction!

Comment: @auburg Sorry my "Post a compilable example in your OP" comment was meant to be addressed to this-me

Comment: Hello, Actually there was some scanning process that was causing this issue. I wasted nearly half a day figuring out what was really happening. Thanks everyone for your help and feel like banging my head for my stupidity

Answer (score 1):

You could try to improve the performance using multiple threads (using Tasks / Threads) and vectorization.
Using System.Numerics you may be able to leverage the power of SIMD, possibly increasing performance 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you should analyze all the mathematical expressions and
   reduce the number of those that can be precalculated:
   (0.27*0.000015)
2. also try to use multiplication instead of Math.Pow if possible: velocity * velocity would be faster than Math.Pow(velocity, 2)
3. if possible you can try Pow approximation algorithms - they are faster but not so precise. Look for more information this article: http://martin.ankerl.com/2007/10/04/optimized-pow-approximation-for-java-and-c-c/
4. Are you using Parallel class for your loop to utilize multicore/multiprocessor of your PC? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd537608(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm already using the TPL libraries on the upper layer that invokes this calculation method.